# Problemas al direccionar una opción en html y javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo la siguiente opción de redireccionamiento en html

```
<li><a  class="tab" id="lineasfactura"  href="#lineas"  data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="visible-xs"></span> <span class="hidden-xs">Líneas</span> </a></li>
```

Al pulsar en esta opción se redirecciona a id=Lineas y presenta una nueva pantalla

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="lineas">
```

La idea es que al pulsar la opción Lineas conseguir lo siguiente:
1)redireccionar a la pantalla anteriormente reseñada id="líneas"
2)mediante id="lineasfactura" poner en marcha el siguiente javascript.

```
$('#lineasfactura').click( function( e ) {
            console.log($("#_id").val());
            e.preventDefault();
            id = $("#_id").val();
            var data = { "id" : id,
                      "factura" :$("#input-numerodefactura"),
                "acreedor_id":$("#input-acreedor"),
                    "recepcion":$("#input-recepcion"),
                          "fecha":$("#input-fecha"),
                "vencimiento":$("#input-vencimiento"),
                "formadepago":$("#input-formadepago"),
                             "iban":$("#input-iban"),
                        "auxiliar":$("#input-auxiliar"),
                       "_token" : $("#_token").val() };
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '/facturasrecibidas/update',
                data: data,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function( linea ){
                }
            });
                       
        });
```

Cambia a la pantalla Lineas

Apunta en la consola ($("#_id").val()),pero el resto de la operación no la realiza , en cambio presenta el siguiente error

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.select is not a function  helpers.js:220:12

$("input[type=text]").focus(function(){    
  this.select();..............esta línea corresponde a helpers.js 220
});
```

Espero haberme explicado
Gracias anticipadas.

Comment: Ya que estás usando _jQuery_, ¿no debería ser `$(this).select();`?

Comment: @Triby No entiendo lo que me comentas. ,no se porque helpers.js devuelve un error ,ya que no programo sobre ese fichero ni se que hace

Comment: Haz el cambio en _helpers.js_ y nos cuentas si funcionó.

Comment: @triby He abierto helpers.js y es eso un archivo de ayuda  escrito en javascript que sirve para realizar tareas accesorias como cambiar formatos ,lanzar mensajes etc.he cambiado la instrucción tal y como me decías y el resultado es :

Comment: @triby       ncaught TypeError: t is undefined
    jQuery 8
        handle
        i
        jt
        jt
        jt
        jt
        param
        ajax
    <anonymous> http://localhost/facturarecibidas/edit/477:724
    jQuery 2
        dispatch
        handle
jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:39737
    jQuery 8
    <anonymous> http://localhost/facturarecibidas/edit/477:724
    jQuery 2

Comment: @triby  Y  localhost/facturarecibidas/edit/477:724  corresponde a la linea   $.ajax({                     que mencionada en mi pregunta y está a continuacióm de  $('#lineasfactura').click( function( e ) {      espero que sirva de ayuda

Comment: ¿Tienes el script para la petición AJAX arriba del HTML?

Comment: @Triby desde HTML llamo a java script con: <li><a  class="tab" id="lineasfactura",tal como indico al principio de mi pregunta, Ajax está en java script

Comment: puedes poner tu html faltante

Comment: @Eduardo Jaramillo Licea Entiendo que quieres ver TODO el html, si es así te eniaré todo el fichero

Comment: @EduardoJaramilloLicea: Dada la imposibilidad de realizar las dos operaciones simultáneas , he optado por otra solución ;Obtener primero todos los datos antes de pasar a la segunda fase

Comment: @Triby  Dada la imposibilidad de realizar las dos operaciones simultáneas , he optado por otra solución ;Obtener primero todos los datos antes de pasar a la segunda fase